# kivy error : * failed to add service - already in use? in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, raspberry-pi4

My Kivy Code not works on raspberry pi4
I've installed every pip kivy but still not work.!

i've get this error in terminal :

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-04-17_18.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python"
[WARNING] [Deprecated  ] Python 2 Kivy support has been deprecated. The Kivy release after 1.11.0 will not support Python 2 anymore
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: egl_rpi
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

can anyone know that wh i've get this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and encountered this problem.

As mentioned in this [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=253712), you need to enable the Legacy GL driver. You can do this by running `sudo raspi-config` and then going into `Advanced Options` > `GL Driver` > Select `Legacy`.

Let me know if you have any questions or problems.